# Javascript form validation(oninput)

Tags: javascript, html

I have two tables and functions. Function validation() validates username character length and checks if the name already exists in an array.

Function myFunction() works with oninput and outputs the text I enter in the username textfield. I would want to change that in the way it would display form validation/the mistakes I'm making while entering text if you get what I mean.

The only problem I have is that "x" . How can I use "if" and "for" validation as an variable so the output will be the mistake.

I hope you understand the concept.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()"></td>
        <td><p id="demo"></p></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form onsubmit="return validacija()">   
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Uporabniško ime:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="upor_ime" name="upor_ime"></td>             
            </tr>           
        </table>
</form>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
       var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }

    function validacija(){
            var upor_ime = document.getElementById("upor_ime");         
            var polje_imen = ["Tilen","Marko","Teja","Tisa","Rok","Luka","Mojca"];

            if (upor_ime.value.length <= 20 && upor_ime.value.length >= 3) {} 
            else {
                    alert("Username has to be between 3-20 characters.");
                }

            for (let i = 0; i < polje_imen.length; i++) {
                if (polje_imen[i] == upor_ime.value) {
                    alert("Uporabniško ime že obstaja.");
                }
            }
       }     
</script>
```

Comment: Check event `change`, add function myFunction within change event so when ever input if changed it updates demo

Comment: @Manjunath oninput does that too when I was using it. What's different with the event change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `<Form>` Tag & `input` Event

---

### [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)

- Wrap a `<form>` tag around all relevant [form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements#Value)
- Reference the `<form>` tag using the [Document.forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms) property.
- Collect all of the `<form>` tag's form controls using [HTMLFormElement.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) property.

**Reference:** [*JavaScript and Forms Tutorial*](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/)

---

### [Form & Form Control Events](https://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/18_forms.html)

Besides the common events like `click`, `<form>` tags and form controls have some exclusive events as well:

#### `<form>`

- [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit)
- [`reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/reset)

#### `<input>`, `<textarea>`

- [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) (including `<select>`)

  - **Trigger:** User must enter data into or change value of the form control, then click anywhere except the form control itself.
- [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)

  - **Trigger:** User enters data into the form control.

---

### [Event Handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)

#### [Onevent Handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Registering_on-event_handlers)

- Try to avoid using the onevent attribute handler:

  ```
  <form id='xForm' onsubmit="return validate()">
  ```
- Although it's not recommended, an onevent property handler is a better alternative:

  ```
  document.forms.xForm.onsubmit = validate;
  ```

  I personally prefer using the previously mentioned event handler because of it's terse syntax.
- The recommended way of event handling is to use [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

  ```
  document.forms.xForm.addEventListener('submit', validate);
  ```

---

### Avoid `alert()`

`alert()` sux, use [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

---

### Demo

```js
var xF = document.forms.xForm;
var fields = xF.elements;
var xI = fields.xInput;
var xM = fields.xMessage;

xF.oninput = validate;

function validate(e) {
  var names = ["tilen", "marko", "teja", "tisa", "rok", "luka", "mojca"];
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (names[i] === xI.value.toLowerCase()) {
      return log(xI.value + " že obstaja.");
    }
  }
  if (xI.value.length > 20 || xI.value.length < 3) {
    return log("uporabniško ime mora biti vsaj 3 in ne sme biti daljše od 20 znakov.");
  } else {
    return log('');
  }
}

function log(msg) {
  var color = msg === '' ? 'black' : 'red';
  Array.from(fields).forEach(function(fc) {
    fc.style.color = color;
  });
  xM.value = msg.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + msg.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  return false;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  font: 400 14px/1.5 Consolas;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 150px;
}

input,
output {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 96%;
}

#xInput {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  padding: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<form id='xForm' width='100%'>

  <table width='100%'>
    <tr>
      <th title="Username">Uporabniško Ime:</th>
      <td><input id="xInput" type="text" autocomplete="off"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th title="Error Message">Obvestilo O Napaki:</th>
      <td><output id="xMessage"></output></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</form>
```